# Clojure use aws jdk's AmazonS3ClientBuilder, but got ClassNotFoundException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, clojure

I have following clojure code

```
(ns com.my.service.resources.s3
  (:require [clojure.tools.logging :refer [error info infof]]
            [clojure.java.io :as io])
  (:import
   [java.io File FileInputStream FileOutputStream]
   java.util.UUID
   [com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3 AmazonS3ClientBuilder]
   [com.amazonaws.services.s3 AmazonS3Client AmazonS3URI]
   [com.amazonaws.services.s3.model DeleteObjectRequest
    GetObjectRequest ObjectMetadata PutObjectRequest]
   [com.amazonaws.services.s3.model AmazonS3Exception]))


(defn- s3-client
  []
  (AmazonS3ClientBuilder/standard()
                                 .withEndpointConfiguration
                                 (AmazonS3ClientBuilder/EndpointConfiguration. "http://localhost:4566" "us-east-1")
                                 .build()))

......
```

However, when I run `lein verify`, I got error below:

```
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder, ......
```

Note that, in my project.clj, I have the dependencies as below:

```
:dependencies
    [ ......
       [com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ssm "1.12.179"]
       [com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 "1.12.179"]
    ......]
```

I assume that should be good for import the AmazonS3ClientBuilder, but not sure why I got the ClassNotFound error. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing. The reason this is not passed is because the package of the AmazonS3ClientBuilder is com.amazonaws.services.s3, not com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3.